# oracle - Select first, second and third greatest numbers over multple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have this table structure

```
CLIENT_ID | QTY_A | QTY_B | QTY_C | QTY_D | QTY_E 
====================================================
1         |     20|     21|     19|   NULL|    30 
----------------------------------------------------
2         |     45|   NULL|     31|     80|    54 
----------------------------------------------------
```

And i am trying to calculate, for wach CLIENT_ID, the first, second and third largest values.

How can i achieve this? Analytic functions cannot help me here, right? I cannot just order by a column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `QTY_A` and  `QTY_B` columns have equal largest values, then you need both of them? or unique?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT` to convert the columns to rows and then the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to number the rows:

```
SELECT client_id,
       type,
       quantity
FROM   (
  SELECT client_id,
         type,
         quantity,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY quantity DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT ( quantity FOR type IN ( qty_a, qty_b, qty_c, qty_d, qty_e ) )
)
WHERE  rn <= 3
```